# Swift5. Protocol extension raises compilation error 'Cannot invoke function with an argument list of type Self'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-protocols, associated-types

I'd like to implement some kind of `Decorator` pattern, which allows to write **reusable decorators**

So I defined 2 protocols. The first one defines a type for a decorator:

```swift
    protocol ViewDecorator {
        associatedtype View: Decoratable
        func decorate(view: View)
    }

    // this is how I expect to use decorator
    class GreenViewDecorator: ViewDecorator {
        typealias View = GreenView

        func decorate(view: GreenView) {
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }
    }
```

The second one defines a type which **decoratable** view should conform to.

```swift
    protocol Decoratable {
        func decorate<T: ViewDecorator>(with decorator: T)
    }

    extension Decoratable where Self: UIView {
        func decorate<T : ViewDecorator>(with decorator: T) {
            decorator.decorate(view: self)
        }
    }

    // exampled of 'decoratable' view
    class GreenView: UIView, Decoratable { }
```

I defined default implementation of function `func decorate<T : ViewDecorator>(with decorator: T)` in the protocol extension. I see it's useful if my view will implement the method by default. I just need it only inherit `Decoratable` protocol. And then I can use it like:

```swift
    // example of using decorator with view
    let decorator = GreenViewDecorator()
    greenView.decorate(with: decorator)
```

But Swift5 compiler raises error at the line `decorator.decorate(view: self)`

> *Cannot invoke 'decorate' with an argument list of type '(view: Self)'*

[image: Compilation error]

```swift
============== TOTAL LISTING ==========
    protocol ViewDecorator {
        associatedtype View: Decoratable
        func decorate(view: View)
    }

    protocol Decoratable {
        func decorate<T: ViewDecorator>(with decorator: T)
    }

    extension Decoratable where Self: UIView {
        func decorate<T : ViewDecorator>(with decorator: T) {
            decorator.decorate(view: self)
        }
    }

    class GreenView: UIView, Decoratable { }

    class GreenViewDecorator: ViewDecorator {
        typealias View = GreenView

        func decorate(view: GreenView) {
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }
    }

    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet var greenView: GreenView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let decorator = GreenViewDecorator()
            greenView.decorate(with: decorator)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the argument is the associated type `View`, but it has not been established anywhere that `Self` is that type, hence you cannot pass an argument of type `Self` without establishing that it is compatible. For example:

```
extension Decoratable where Self: UIView {
    func decorate<T: ViewDecorator>(with decorator: T) where T.View == Self {
        decorator.decorate(view: self)
    }
}
```

(However, if you do this, you will have trouble conforming to the `Decoratable` protocol because it requires this method for *any* `ViewDecorator`. You can change the protocol to also have the same `T.View == Self` limitation.)

Comment: Thank you. It's work.
`protocol Decoratable {
    func decorate<T: ViewDecorator>(with decorator: T) where T.View == Self
}`